# Python copy data from 1 df to first matching row in other df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Basically I got a df1 that looks like this:

```
  Ticker      Date
0   AAPL  20200501
1   AAPL  20200501
2   AAPL  20200502
3   AAPL  20200502
4   TSLA  20200501
5   TSLA  20200501
6   TSLA  20200502
7   TSLA  20200502
```

and a df2 that looks like this:

```
  Ticker      Date  Comm.
0   AAPL  20200501    500
1   AAPL  20200502    800
2   TSLA  20200501   1000
3   TSLA  20200502   1500
```

how do I get df1 to look like this?

```
  Ticker      Date  Comm.
0   AAPL  20200501    500
1   AAPL  20200501      0
2   AAPL  20200502    800
3   AAPL  20200502      0
4   TSLA  20200501   1000
5   TSLA  20200501      0
6   TSLA  20200502   1500
7   TSLA  20200502      0
```

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL','TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA'],
                'Date': [20200501, 20200501, 20200502, 20200502, 20200501, 20200501, 20200502, 20200502]})
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'TSLA', 'TSLA'],
               'Date': [20200501, 20200502, 20200501, 20200502],
                'Comm.': [500, 800, 1000, 1500]})
print(df2)

output = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL','TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA'],
                'Date': [20200501, 20200501, 20200502, 20200502, 20200501, 20200501, 20200502, 20200502],
                   'Comm.': [500, 0, 800, 0, 1000, 0, 1500, 0]})
print(output)
```

PS: stack wont let me post this question because my question has to much code and not enough text so im typing this placeholder text here but im guessing that you get what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` to map the `Comm.` column, then `mask` to place `0` where the values are duplicated:

```
df1['Comm.'] = (df1.merge(df2, on=['Ticker','Date'], how='left')
                   ['Comm.']
                   .mask(df1.duplicated(['Ticker','Date']), 0)
               )
```

Output:

```
  Ticker      Date  Comm.
0   AAPL  20200501    500
1   AAPL  20200501      0
2   AAPL  20200502    800
3   AAPL  20200502      0
4   TSLA  20200501   1000
5   TSLA  20200501      0
6   TSLA  20200502   1500
7   TSLA  20200502      0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need!